# How to search a directory in unix and copy it to another Directory

Tags: shell, unix

Suppose I have one folder XYZ having some directory and files.I want to search this XYZ folder in the /tmp directory of the linux machine and then copy the entire folder to /tmp/lib/ folder.

Can anyone please tell the unix command to achieve this.

Thanks !!

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the related site http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux) although I think you're expected to show your work there too ;-) . Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use on of these commands:

To copy:

```
rsync -a /tmp/XYZ/ /tmp/lib/XYZ/
cp -R /tmp/XYZ/ /tmp/lib/
```

To search for a file with `abc` in its name:

```
find /tmp/XYZ -name \*abc\*
```